# Conditional format formula IF/AND

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to populate a cell using conditional formatting based on a couple of variables.

Essentially, if a cell in column A is blank, but the corresponding cell in column B is not, display "BATTERY" in column A.
If both the cell in column A and B is filled. Do nothing.
If both the cell in column A and B are empty. Do nothing.

I've tried nested IFs but can't get anything working...

```
=IF($A=""(IF($B<>"")),"Battery","")
```

The sheet is not free entry, data is being pulled through from other sheets so it has to be done in conditional formatting.

Comment: Note that **"Conditional formula"** and **"conditional format formula"** are two very different things. Yorik's answer is the first, the second has to return either of TRUE or FALSE [ as in the first parameter to IF(...) ], if TRUE a FORMATTING is to be set for that cell (no VALUE can be shown) .

Comment: You may consider formatting the cells that meet the conditions. Such as using `=IF(AND(A1="",B1<>""),1,0)` and setting fill color for cells in column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an AND clause. The syntax would be:

`=IF(AND(Something is True, Something else is True), Value if True, Value if False)`

Manual: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-with-and-or-and-not-functions-d895f58c-b36c-419e-b1f2-5c193a236d97

Answer (score 0):

If BATTERY is to appear in Column A then Column A will *never* be blank. Perhaps you meant put the result in Column D?

Nonetheless, Here is a screenshot of two examples I made:

First is applying Conditional Formatting when the formula `=AND($A2="",$B2<>"")` is TRUE. This satisfies the condition when only B gets data, formatting takes effect.

Second is throwing the *result* BATTERY announcement outside Column A thus source data remains intact (in this case of interest, blank). But, not necessary to do Conditional Formatting which you are seeking.

On cell D3 `=IF(B3<>"",IF(A3<>"","","BATTERY"),"")` in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I perhaps struggled to explain exactly what I wanted.

I managed to solve it as the data was already going through a separate sheet which was designed to trim some of the unwanted language from user inputs.

It turns out that on that sheet, there was always a blank cell on the line where 'batteries' were listed, but ONLY ever against 'batteries', so I managed to get around this with:

```
=IF(othersheet!A1=0,othersheet!A1,"Batteries")
```

I'm both happy, and frustrated, that the answer was so simple!!